# Configure Web2Py to use Anaconda Python

Tags: python-2.7, web2py, anaconda, gensim

I am new to Web2Py and Python stack. I need to use a module in my Web2Py application which uses "gensim" and "nltk" libraries. I tried installing these into my Python 2.7 on a Windows 7 environment but came across several errors due to some issues with "numpy" and "scipy" installations on Windows 7. Then I ended up resolving those errors by uninstalling Python 2.7 and instead installing Anaconda Python which successfully installed the required "gensim" and "nltk" libraries.

So, at this stage I am able to see all these "gensim" and "nltk" libraries resolving properly without any error in "Spyder" and "PyCharm". However, when I run my application in Web2Py, it still complains about "gensim" and gives this error: `<type 'exceptions.ImportError'> No module named gensim`

My guess is if I can configure Web2Py to use the Anaconda Python then this issue would be resolved.

I need to know if it's possible to configure Web2Py to use Anaconda Python and if it is then how do I do that?

Otherwise, if someone knows of some other way resolve that "gensim" error in Web2Py kindly share your thoughts.

All your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you download the web2py Windows binary, or are you running from source? How are you starting web2py?

Comment: I believe I downloaded the Windows binary and running Web2Py by double clicking the file: "web2py.exe".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows binary includes it's own Python interpreter and will therefore not see any packages you have in your local Python installation.

If you already have Python installed, you should instead run web2py from source.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Anthony. That solved my issues. Basically, I followed the instructions mentioned at: [link](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview) in the section for "On Windows (source web2py distribution)" and configured PyCharm to use the Web2Py source distribution while launching along with Anaconda Python. That took care of all the missing library errors.